# Adding delay to website screenshot

Tags: vb.net

I have a program(Currently winform) that loads a website, takes a screenshot and converts to bitmap, and then saves. The issue I am running into is, it fails to load data into the website. Why I think it does this is, it takes the screenshot to fast and does not have time to load fully.

Example:
Under the 'Statistics' there should be a bunch of information that seems to not of loaded yet.

[image: Example]

I have tried putting a `Threading.sleep`in a few places, but it does not change the results.

**Code**

```
    Private Sub btnDrawBmp_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Capture.Click
    ' Initialize new Hidden Browser control and navigate to site
    Dim Browser As New WebBrowser
    Browser.ScrollBarsEnabled = False
    Browser.Navigate("http://xxxxx/LiveStats/")
    ' Initialize Handler for DocumentCompleted event and wait for that event to fire
    AddHandler Browser.DocumentCompleted, AddressOf Browser_DocumentCompleted
    While Browser.ReadyState <> WebBrowserReadyState.Complete
        Application.DoEvents()
    End While
    ' Housekeeping
    Browser.Dispose()
End Sub
Private Sub Browser_DocumentCompleted(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs)
    ' If sender was a WebBrowser then initialize a reference to it otherwise throw an exception
    Dim Browser As WebBrowser = DirectCast(sender, WebBrowser)
    ' Set browser start size, determine scrollheight, resize browser to match scrollheight
    Browser.ClientSize = New Size(1024, 768)
    Dim Height As Integer = Browser.Document.Body.ScrollRectangle.Bottom
    Browser.ClientSize = New Size(1024, Height)
    ' Initialize bitmap to match width & scrollheight for fullsize screen capture
    Dim Bmp = New Bitmap(Browser.Bounds.Width, Height)
    ' Capture fullsize screen shot
    Browser.DrawToBitmap(Bmp, Browser.Bounds)
    Bmp.Save("c:\temp1.png")
    ' Resize Browser for thumbnail capture
    Browser.ClientSize = New Size(1024, 768)
    ' Inialize a new bitmap with the same client area size as the browser
    Dim Bmp2 = New Bitmap(Browser.Bounds.Width, Browser.Bounds.Height)
    ' Perform screen capture, convert it to a thumbnail, and save
    Browser.DrawToBitmap(Bmp2, Browser.Bounds)
    Bmp2 = Bmp2.GetThumbnailImage(160, 120, Nothing, IntPtr.Zero)
    Bmp2.Save("c:\temp2.png")
    ' Housekeeping
    Bmp.Dispose()
    Bmp2.Dispose()
End Sub
```

**Updated code that is still having issues:**

Note: Only 2 objects on the form is a button and a browser.

```
Private Sub btnDrawBmp_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Capture.Click
    ' Initialize new Hidden Browser control and navigate to site
    'Dim Browser As New WebBrowser
    Dim Browser = wb
    Browser.ScrollBarsEnabled = False
    Browser.Navigate("http://ssgw8sr01/LiveStats/")
    'Browser.Navigate("http://google.com")
    ' Initialize Handler for DocumentCompleted event and wait for that event to fire
    AddHandler Browser.DocumentCompleted, AddressOf Browser_DocumentCompleted
    While Browser.ReadyState <> WebBrowserReadyState.Complete
        Application.DoEvents()
    End While
    ' Housekeeping
    Browser.Dispose()
End Sub
Private Sub Browser_DocumentCompleted(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs)
    If (e.Url = wb.Url) AndAlso (wb.ReadyState = WebBrowserReadyState.Complete) Then
        ' If sender was a WebBrowser then initialize a reference to it otherwise throw an exception
        Dim Browser As WebBrowser = DirectCast(sender, WebBrowser)
        ' Set browser start size, determine scrollheight, resize browser to match scrollheight
        Browser.ClientSize = New Size(1024, 768)
        Dim Height As Integer = Browser.Document.Body.ScrollRectangle.Bottom
        Browser.ClientSize = New Size(1024, Height)
        ' Initialize bitmap to match width & scrollheight for fullsize screen capture
        Dim Bmp = New Bitmap(Browser.Bounds.Width, Height)
        ' Capture fullsize screen shot
        Browser.DrawToBitmap(Bmp, Browser.Bounds)
        Bmp.Save("c:\temp1.png")
        ' Resize Browser for thumbnail capture
        Browser.ClientSize = New Size(1024, 768)
        ' Inialize a new bitmap with the same client area size as the browser
        Dim Bmp2 = New Bitmap(Browser.Bounds.Width, Browser.Bounds.Height)
        ' Perform screen capture, convert it to a thumbnail, and save
        Browser.DrawToBitmap(Bmp2, Browser.Bounds)
        Bmp2 = Bmp2.GetThumbnailImage(160, 120, Nothing, IntPtr.Zero)
        Bmp2.Save("c:\temp2.png")
        ' Housekeeping
        Bmp.Dispose()
        Bmp2.Dispose()
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: You should probably use an async version of page loader that notifies you when loading is completed so you don't run into these issues

Comment: @VSG24 Not sure what "async" is. Tried to google it tied to my question and did not find much

Comment: Just search for "VB.Net asynchronous programming"

Comment: @VSG24 I do vb.net, but I will see how much since I can make out of it. Thanks for the input.

Comment: Looks like the stats section is loaded asynchronously (through some sort of XMLHttpRequest implementation), so even if the DocumentCompleted event is triggered, it doesn't mean that all the elements in the page are available. If that's the case, you should start a monitoring routine (from the DocumentCompleted event handler) that queries the [document object](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.webbrowser.document(v=vs.110).aspx) of the WebBrowser control and look for "known" elements and IDs to determine when those dynamic sections have been successfully loaded.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add this in your doc_completed event, change the WB variables, i'm on my phone and it's a PITA.

I think you need to wait on the readystate to reach complete.

```
If (e.Url = wb.Url) AndAlso (wb.ReadyState = WebBrowserReadyState.Complete) Then
 ' If sender was a WebBrowser then initialize a reference to it otherwise throw an exception
    Dim Browser As WebBrowser = DirectCast(sender, WebBrowser)
    ' Set browser start size, determine scrollheight, resize browser to match scrollheight
    Browser.ClientSize = New Size(1024, 768)
    Dim Height As Integer = Browser.Document.Body.ScrollRectangle.Bottom
    Browser.ClientSize = New Size(1024, Height)
    ' Initialize bitmap to match width & scrollheight for fullsize screen capture
    Dim Bmp = New Bitmap(Browser.Bounds.Width, Height)
    ' Capture fullsize screen shot
    Browser.DrawToBitmap(Bmp, Browser.Bounds)
    Bmp.Save("c:\temp1.png")
    ' Resize Browser for thumbnail capture
    Browser.ClientSize = New Size(1024, 768)
    ' Inialize a new bitmap with the same client area size as the browser
    Dim Bmp2 = New Bitmap(Browser.Bounds.Width, Browser.Bounds.Height)
    ' Perform screen capture, convert it to a thumbnail, and save
    Browser.DrawToBitmap(Bmp2, Browser.Bounds)
    Bmp2 = Bmp2.GetThumbnailImage(160, 120, Nothing, IntPtr.Zero)
    Bmp2.Save("c:\temp2.png")
    ' Housekeeping
    Bmp.Dispose()
    Bmp2.Dispose()
End If
```

EDIT:

This has been tested, and works like a charm... even on slow loading sites. It will not create the screenshot until it is completely done loading.

```
Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        WebBrowser1.Navigate("http:\\www.msn.com")
    End Sub

    Private Sub WebBrowser1_DocumentCompleted(sender As Object, e As WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs) Handles WebBrowser1.DocumentCompleted
        If (e.Url = WebBrowser1.Url) AndAlso (WebBrowser1.ReadyState = WebBrowserReadyState.Complete) Then
            getBitmap(WebBrowser1).Save("C:\Users\Anthony Wiles\Desktop\myScreenShot.png")
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Function getBitmap(ByVal pCtrl As Control) As Drawing.Bitmap
        Dim myBmp As New Bitmap(pCtrl.Width, pCtrl.Height)
        Dim g As Graphics = Graphics.FromImage(myBmp)
        Dim pt As Point = pCtrl.Parent.PointToScreen(pCtrl.Location)
        g.CopyFromScreen(pt, Point.Empty, myBmp.Size)
        g.Dispose()
        Return myBmp
    End Function
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I updated my code to match, and at this point it will not even save a screenshot. Any ideas why? Note: I also changed the url to google to just test with the same results.

Comment: Is the event firing?

Comment: It was skipping the 'if' command. I changed from 'Dim Browser As New WebBrowser' to 'Dim Browser = wb'. It is still giving the same results of the screen shot without the information. Also, I updated the top code with how it currently is.

Comment: So it is taking screenshots, but still to early? Does this work with lets say... MSN.com or something slowish to load?

Comment: Just tried MSN.com, and it took a blank white screenshot.

Comment: The code you're using now is correct, at least the stuff I gave you. You have a problem with how you're creating the screenshot. Even if I wait completely until the browser is 100% loaded, by manually waiting... and using your code to take a snapshot of the control, it's a blank white screen.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/116424/discussion-between-tonyw-and-dwb).

Comment: Joined chat if you get online today-